# I want to capture the scroll bottom action to load more records.Thanks

Tags: lightning-aura-components, scrolling

I have aura iteration with the set defined height,in which I am calling another component . I want to capture the scroll bottom action to load more records.

```
<div class="slds-scrollable" style="height: 40rem; width: 34rem;">

        <aura:iteration items="{!v.timeLineItems}" var="item" end="{!v.displayCount}">

                <c:ActivityTimeLine_Item activityType="{!item.ActivityTimelineType}" itemDetail="{!item}"/>

        </aura:iteration>
    </div>
```

Comment: <div class="slds-scrollable" style="height: 40rem; width: 34rem;">

        <aura:iteration items="{!v.timeLineItems}" var="item" end="{!v.displayCount}">
        
                <c:ActivityTimeLine_Item activityType="{!item.ActivityTimelineType}" itemDetail="{!item}"/>
    
        </aura:iteration>
        </div>

Comment: Hi Pavan, and welcome to SFSE! In the future, you can use the `{}` button to format your code correctly. I've fixed this for you this time, as well as adding a tag so that the appropriate people will see your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Data Table with attribute `onloadmore` attribute and fetch records again passing the limit or number of records you want to load. 
Here is the link for example-
[Example](https://forcerangers.wordpress.com/2018/06/20/lazyloading/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think datatable is for list view's, I have to pass task list in timeline custom component and when you scroll it should load more records.

Comment: I got the solution.. var element = document.getElementById('activityDivId');      if((element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop - element.clientHeight) < 20 )
        {  you can right your loadmore logic here.
} it worked for me.